# How to specify one of two props required in Flowjs?

Tags: flowtype

I have various React components that can have different functionality when different props are passed in. Often I come across some branching logic where if `prop1` is present, do one thing, but if `prop2` is present do something else.

One example could be two change handlers for an element with an input that take different arguments.

Is there a way to specify in Flowjs that one of the two handlers are required?

Comment: I think your question should be applicable to any environment that your Flow code targets, including, but not limited to, React, and everything else. Would it not make more sense for the question title and body of your question to *exclude* React? I'm just suggesting, that's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately, the Flow type annotation that you want can be applied in contexts beyond React. Generally, if you want an exclusive-or type check you can do this:

```
type Something = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2?: null
}

type Another = {
    prop1?: null,
    prop2: number
}

function foo(parameter: Something | Another) {

}

foo({ prop1: 10 }); // Good
foo({ prop2: 10 }); // Good
foo({ prop1: 10, prop2: 10 }); // Bad
```

If you want an inclusive-or type check, you can do this:

```
type Something = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2?: null
}

type Another = {
    prop1?: null,
    prop2: number
}

type SomethingAndAnother = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: number
}

function foo(parameter: Something | Another | SomethingAndAnother) {

}

foo({ something: 10, prop1: 10 }); // Good
foo({ something: 10 }); // Bad
foo({ prop1: 10 }); // Good
foo({ prop2: 10 }); // Good
foo({ prop1: 10, prop2: 10 }); // Good
```

In React, you define the type on the `props` property, like so:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  props: Something | Another;

  render(): React.Element {
    return (
      // ....
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an enum:

```
type Props = {
  ['prop1' | 'prop2']: string,
}
```